# How can I preview Rails e-mail messages in QA?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The [Rails guides describe previewing e-mail messages](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/action_mailer_basics.html#previewing-emails) but only mention localhost:3000.  Is there any way to get this working in QA?

Comment: What do you mean "get this working in QA?" Those previews are literally just that: a preview of the email, demonstrating the formatting and content that a user would see if they received one. If you're thinking of the preview as a test email, complete with recipient and so on, that's not what it is.

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't understand.  The preview links open a *preview* of the e-mail message in the *browser*, but they only seem to work on *localhost*.  Opening the link the same path, but QA server as the host (e.g. to let another person preview the various possibilities) did not work for me.  If you have a dozen different e-mails, each in 10 languages, and each with both HTML and text versions, that's 240 different permutations.  Previewing is the most convenient way to see these that I know of.  Furthermore it is easy to use the params hash to control data used in the preview.

Comment: Now I understand your initial question, but I wonder why you didn't just write all that from the start.

Comment: I'm not sure how else what I wrote could be understood.  If you know that the preview is done in the browser, hitting your rails server, what else could it mean to get it working in QA?  Anyone who doesn't already know that isn't going to have an answer, so I didn't see any reason to repeat things that everyone who might answer the question already knows.

Comment: By your own logic, if you don't already recognize the ambiguity of your question, there's nothing to be gained by explaining it to you. Best of luck.

Comment: I think you're projecting, as I've been nothing but polite. I won't be replying further since this thread appears to have gone off the rails, so to speak. Again, best of luck with all of your issues.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with MarsAtomic that your question was not clear, but after reading the comments I believe I understand now.

Your QA server seems to not run with `Rails.env` set to "development" but maybe production (or a custom environment like `qa` or `staging`). The previews are only available in the development environment by default, however.

You can enable them with a config option

```rb
# config/environments/staging.rb

Rails.application.configure do
  # other configs
  config.action_mailer.show_previews = true
end
```

If you use the same environment in QA as in production, don't change this in `production.rb` as then everyone can see mail previews in your real app. You have to distinguish between production and QA in this case.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/railtie.rb#L24

Comment: can you tell me exactly what was unclear about the question?

Comment: It is not clear what QA is? Is it a different Rails environment? Is it the production Rails environment but deployed to a different server? QA means something different in almost every company.

Comment: okay, thanks for explaining what was unclear.  QA is a separate server with it's own environment configuration file that is similar enough to production to allow human testing but different in various important aspects.

Comment: I hear what you mean about different companies using the terminology differently.  All but one company I've worked for used "QA" as I describe, but there was one that used "test", "development", "staging" and "user acceptance" as all synonymous.  They didn't even use the term "QA" IIRC, so it didn't occur to me that anyone wouldn't understand QA.  But you're right, there are companies that use all manner of definitions for the various server environmental stages between development and production.

Comment: Yes, so in most companies I worked this is called staging. However, the naming staging vs QA is less problematic but to answer the question it's important to know how how it is setup. Does it use the production configuration or development (see my answer I just assumed that it's a dedicated environment configuration) etc?

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider accepting or upvoting it.